# How to implement Custom AuthorizationEndPoint in Spring OAuth2?

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to implement my own logic for authorization to satisfy our project requirements. Can any one please help to find a way to implement my own authorization end point?

Answer (score 0):

When you say Custom, does it mean a different standalone authorization server. Need more information to answer your question.

Comment: Yes authorization server is standalone. Actually what my requirement is have to scopes and resource tables for users and validate them when client is getting authorized. Here I'm removing the necessity of sending oauth scopes as parameter. I would rather validate them during the time of authorization. So I would like to have custom authorization endpoint and process my requirement. I hope you understand what I want to say...

Comment: I have created the custom authorization end point by using @FrameWorkEndpoint but I'm getting error like this - Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'oauth2AuthorizationEndpoint' bean method

Comment: Here is my understanding, you want to authenticate a user after authorization or may authenticate and authorize at the same point by validating DB entry. Correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: Ya I want to validate the user at the time of authorisation. Here I'm gonna validate the user restrictions like IP, domain address of the client i.e., user